# Is there an option to translate the content using FB Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using FB Graph API to get the posts and comments from a Page. Just wanted to know if there is an option to convert the comments /content of any post to required language.

Answer (score 0):

No, Facebook does not offer an API for that.

---

I am not sure if they are still using Bing for their live translation of content, or have implemented their own system by now. (I think I remember that in the past it used to say below such translations that they were handled through Bing – but that note seems to have gone.)

But using a service such as Bing or Google is probably your best option. (Not sure if they offers APIs for that for free though.)